# Publishing Images from authoring site to public site with image rendition enabled

Tags: publishing-site, cross-site-publishing, image-rendition

I'm trying to publish document/image library from an authoring site to publish site but could not understand how it will work.

I'm following Cross Site Publishing concep where i have Product Catalog Site Collection (authoring SC) and Public Site Collection, on Product Catalog SC I have a document library with image Renditions enabled. I enabled Image Library as Catalog, made it anonymous, rebuild index.  I do not have any clue how can i access image with renditions. What should be the url like publicsite.com\mylibrary\image1.jpg?renditionid=1 (working with SP 2013)

My main objective is to move images from one site collection to other public facing site collection, if there is some other approach that can help, please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on articles written by Waldek Mastykarz which investigates a lot on Cross-Site Publishing features.

According to him, and confirmed by myself:

> By default SharePoint 2013 allows you to apply Image Renditions using the UI to images from the same Site Collection only.

Ref: [Using Image Renditions with images from other Site Collections](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/using-image-renditions-with-images-from-other-site-collections/)

Answer (score 0):

URL would be something like:
productcatalogsite.com\mylibrary\image1.jpg?renditionid=1

When you apply rendition to your image, those will be renditions defined in public SC and not authoring site.There is a chance that rendition with a particular ID might have different dimension in the public website and in the authoring site.

You can also use size based renditions using Width and Height query string parameters.